# Ruby serialize struct with JSON

Tags: ruby, json, serialization

I am trying to serialize a simple struct to JSON which works fine, but I can't get it to create an instance of that struct from the JSON. Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

Person = Struct.new(:name, :age)

json = Person.new('Adam', 19).to_json
puts json

me = JSON.load(json)
puts me.name
```

And I get the following output:

```
"#<struct Person name=\"Adam\", age=19>"
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse': 746: unexpected token at '"#<struct Person name=\"Adam\", age=19>"' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:309:in `load'
    from why.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case, `person.to_json` is not doing what you expect.

When you `require 'json'`, the JSON library inserts a `#to_json` method on `Object` that is a fallback if there's no specialized `#to_json` method provided elsewhere. [This inserted method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON/Ext/Generator/GeneratorMethods/Object.html) is basically the same as calling `#to_s#to_json` on an object.

In the case of your `Person` class here, `#to_s` outputs the [standard `Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s), which, by default, doesn't provide a string parseable by the JSON library.

However, `Struct` *does* provide a `#to_h` method that can be used to convert that struct to a `Hash`, and `Hash` is (upon requiring the JSON library) aware of how to generate a JSON parseable output.

So simply changing:

```
json = Person.new('Adam', 19).to_json
puts json
```

to:

```
person = Person.new('Adam', 19)
puts person.to_h.to_json
```

will do what you expect.

(An aside, I would actually recommend implementing `#to_json` on the `Person` class directly as calling `#to_h#to_json` violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).)

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I would just like to note for anyone reading this in the future that the to_h method was added in ruby 2.0, so if you're using 1.9.3 like I was you'll have to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define a struct with a `to_json` method. Depends if you're happy with calling `to_h.to_json`. If it's only called once internally in a class, it may be tolerable and ignore this. But if the struct is used throughout a system below is a convient helper method on the struct.

```
require 'struct'
require 'json'

MyStruct = Struct.new(:foo, :bar) do
  def to_json
    to_h.to_json
  end
end

simple_struct = MyStruct.new("hello", "world")
simple_struct.to_json

# => "{\"foo\":\"hello\",\"bar\":\"world\"}"
```