# How do I access an API service that doesn't have a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

So I want to access Glot.io that has just a [barebones RESTful API](https://github.com/prasmussen/glot-snippets/tree/master/api_docs) from my Rails App.

Glot.io requires me to create an account and generates an API key for me -- pretty standard.

At a high-level, what is the best way for me to approach this?

Create an initializer file called `glot.rb` and what should I include there? Just my `ENV_VARS` to access the API service? Or do I not need that?

Then using the docs available [to CREATE a snippet](https://github.com/prasmussen/glot-snippets/blob/master/api_docs/create_snippet.md), what's the best approach to actually doing that? Should I use a CURL gem like [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) to re-create this `POST` request?

```
curl --request POST \
     --header 'Authorization: Token 99090-7abba-12389abcde' \
     --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
     --data '{"language": "python", "title": "test", "public": false, "files": [{"name": "main.py", "content": "print(42)"}]}' \
     --url 'https://snippets.glot.io/snippets'
```

If so, what might the above look like?

Ideally I would love to get a high-level overview of the approach and then some code snippets of how I might proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a library (either create my own gem, or if just using it here, then in /lib) using net/http.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

This is a very basic example, and could be done a number of ways. This example will allow you to to instantiate SnippetApi and set the URL. You can then call new_snippet, which will take the URL that you supplied, and make the API call.

To continue extending, you can change *def new_snippet* to *def new_snippet(data)*, and then supply the data with your call.

Note: the filename should be *snippet_api.rb* to ensure that the "rails magic" works for autoloading.

lib/snippet_api.rb

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

class SnippetApi

   def initialize(url, api_token = ENV['API_TOKEN'])
      @url = url
      @api_token = api_token
    end

    def url
      @url
    end

    def api_token
      @api_token
    end

  def new_snippet

    # https://snippets.glot.io/snippets
    uri = URI.parse(self.url)
    post_object = {'language': 'python', 'title': 'test', 'public': false, 'files': [{'name': 'main.py', 'content': 'print(42)'}]}

    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Token #{self.api_token}"})
    req.body = "[ #{post_object} ]"
    res = https.request(req)
    puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
  end

end
```

Usage

```
2.3.0 :001 > snippet_api = SnippetApi.new('https://snippets.glot.io/snippets')
 => #<SnippetApi:0x00000003b6bc20 @url="https://snippets.glot.io/snippets"> 
2.3.0 :002 > snippet_api.new_snippet
Response 404 Not Found: {"message":"Wrong auth token"}
```

To ensure that files in /lib are loaded, be sure to add this to application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

**Usage with API Token**

```
[brian@...]$ export API_TOKEN='token from env'

2.3.0 :001 > snippet_api = SnippetApi.new('https://snippets.glot.io/snippets')
 => #<SnippetApi:0x0000000342e8e0 @url="https://snippets.glot.io/snippets", @api_token="token from env"> 
2.3.0 :002 > snippet_api.api_token
 => "token from env" 
2.3.0 :003 > snippet_api = SnippetApi.new('https://snippets.glot.io/snippets','from init')
 => #<SnippetApi:0x000000033a60d0 @url="https://snippets.glot.io/snippets", @api_token="from init"> 
2.3.0 :004 > snippet_api.api_token
 => "from init"
```

Edit 1: Added information about loading lib files.

Comment: No problem :). just want to point out as well - to make sure that /lib is loaded, you'll want to add *config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]* to your application.rb

Comment: 1 more - the filename must be snippet_api.rb, unless you change the class to something else. For instance ClassName would be class_name.rb. That ensures the rails magic works.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: One question, where do I specify my API token? I assumed I would do it in an initializer file, and just set to the appropriate `ENV_VAR`, but what would that look like in the initializer file? Do I have to specify it as a class?

Comment: Ok so I did it, with the correct API token, and I got this message back: `Response 400 Bad Request: {"message":"Invalid json"}` Any ideas why this may be the case? I used the snippet from the example in the API docs - https://github.com/prasmussen/glot-snippets/blob/master/api_docs/create_snippet.md Ideas?

Comment: Doing some debugging, this is what the `req.body` looks like (aka the JSON sent to the API): `> req.body
=> "[ {:language=>\"python\", :title=>\"test\", :public=>false, :files=>[{:name=>\"main.py\", :content=>\"print(42)\"}]} ]"
` Ideas?

Comment: Apologies, I am light on time for the next few days, but I would look at to_json/as_json options. Using struct may help to create the object as well as well, such as in this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313102/ruby-serialize-struct-with-json

Comment: On the money, ONCE again. adding `require json` to the top and then just simply adding `.to_json` to the end of my main `post_object` assignment worked. One more thing I had to tweak was this line: `req.body = "[ #{post_object} ]"`. Once I changed that to a normal assignment like so: `req.body = post_object`, and it works like a charm. The last bit is how to structure the API token. How do I set it up such that it I abstract that token out and just use `ENV_VARS`? Do I have to declare that in this file? That feels weird if that's the case.

Comment: I've updated code to allow you to either retrieve the API Token from the environment, or set it when instantiating explicitly. Explicit will override the environment, but will not change what is in the environment in this example.

Comment: By the way, there was an issue with the syntax of the `self.api_token` call within the `initheader`. I figured it out and fixed it in your answer for completeness sake.